# Android create folders in Internal memory issue

Tags: android, memory, internal

I have a little issue with creating folders for my application in Internal Memory. I'm using this piece of code :

```
    public static void createFoldersInInternalStorage(Context context){
    try {

        File usersFolder = context.getDir("users", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File fileWithinMyDir = new File(usersFolder, "users.txt"); //Getting a file within the dir.
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.

        File dataFolder = context.getDir("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File fileWithinMyDir2 = new File(dataFolder, "data.txt"); //Getting a file within the dir.
        FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir2); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.

        File publicFolder = context.getDir("public", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File fileWithinMyDir3 = new File(publicFolder, "public.txt"); //Getting a file within the dir.
        FileOutputStream out3 = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir3); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So folders are created but in front of their name there is the beginning  `"app_"` : `app_users`, `app_data`, `app_public`. Is there a way to create the folders with the name given by me? And another question : I want to first create folder `Documents` and than all other folders `"Data, Public, Users"` on it.... And the last question : How can I give the right folder path if I wanted to create a file in `Documents/Users/myfile.txt` in Internal Memory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
File myDir = context.getFilesDir();
String filename = "documents/users/userId/imagename.png";
File file = new File(myDir, filename);
file.createNewFile();
file.mkdirs();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
fos.write(mediaCardBuffer);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create the folders with the name given by me?

Use `getFilesDir()` and Java file I/O instead of `getDir()`.

> How can I give the right folder path if I wanted to create a file in Documents/Users/myfile.txt in Internal Memory?

Use `getFilesDir()` and Java file I/O, such as the `File` constructor that takes a `File` and a `String` to assemble a path.

Comment: I just tried this and it's not creating file or the folders : `File usersFolder = context.getFilesDir();
     File fileWithinMyDir = new File(usersFolder, "documents/users/users.txt"); //Getting a file within the dir.
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
  out.write("adasdasdasd".getBytes());`

Comment: @Bombastic: Of course. The directories don't exist. You have to create the directories. This is standard Java I/O, what you should have learned when you learned Java. Use `mkdirs()` on a `File` object pointing at your deepest directory to create the directory tree to that point.

Comment: Is there any limit of depth when I'm creating folders in Internal Memory? because now I'm using the code above + `file.mkdirs()` before `outputstream` and it's throwing me an `FileNotFoundException` on the line with `outputstream`. The path that I'm trying to create is `documents/users/userId/3456.png`

Comment: @Bombastic: There is no limit on `mkdirs()` that I am aware of. Again, call `mkdirs()` on the *directory*. If you call it on the *file*, it will create a directory with the name of your file, which means you can't then create a file with that same name. See http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CreateDir.html